# calendar /date picker for Farsi language

Tags: android, date, calendar

I am looking for a calendar/date picker to support the Iran calendar (which work week starts on Saturdays) and also runs from right to left (so Saturday will be on the furthest right column and Friday furthest left)

most existing libraries I found don't have the flexibility of both (the image attached shows one i found that has work week starts on Saturday, which is great, but i need it "flip/flopped" [flip flop please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbjvL.png)

Comment: can you share the name of your library with the link ?

Comment: hello @UmarHussain
MaterialDateTimePicker
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker
although I dont love this, was hoping to find a better one

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [HeroDatePicker](https://github.com/hamid97m/HeroDatePicker) too!